# What's the best way to connect to an Oracle DB from BizTalk 2006 (not R2)?

Tags: oracle, biztalk, adapter

I need to call a stored procedure in Oracle from an orchestration. I am running BizTalk 2006 (not R2).  Which way is best?  Are there others?

1. BizTalk Adapters for Enterprise Applications
2. BizTalk LOB Adapters

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an Oracle Adapter from the code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/BizTalk_Oracle_adapter.aspx

There is also a good blog post on it here:

http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/03/12/a-walk-through-the-biztalk-2006-oracle-adapter/

Comment: Interesting.  We're trying to stay on the supported portions of the MS Platform, hence the reference to the two MS provided options.  What would drive you to the CodeProject's adapter versus the ones I mentioned in the original post?

Comment: Generally we also stay on the MS platform, but you asked for an alternative. Main reason for using Open Source vs. MS, is that with MS if you are stuck then you are stuck. If you use Open Source you have the "possibility" of going into the code and fixing it.